# cloudera installation failure ec2-user instead of root

Tags: amazon-ec2, installation, cloudera

I get the error during cloudera 5 installation on my ec2 redhat 7 system cluster ...

during the installation of cloudera the installation is interrupted and I get the message

```
Cluster Installation
Installation failed on all hosts.

0 of 1 host(s) completed successfully.
Uninstalled on 1 host(s) after installation failure.

Retry | Details
Installation failed. Failed to copy installation files.

Failed to copy installation files. (Current Step) 
Please login as the user "ec2-user" rather than the user "root".
```

I have got no idea how to fix it and I can not find information on the web on this issue...

Answer (score 0):

What a stupid mistake. When I chose the options in the beginning, it asked what user to choose for installation. I mistakenly chose the default "root". As soon as you change the user to "ec2-user" the installation works fine.

Comment: This is an answer.